# Expose filter multiple search in drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have one Drupal website where there is a list of all temples, mosques, church etc available. Now i want a search form in my front page where user can search temples, mosques, church etc. I am using View exposed filter for searching results. But problem is when i go to add filter criteria then It ask for specific CCK field to exposed.

In Drupal machine name is always unique. So for temples it takes different machine name and for mosques it takes different.

I want only one search form where user can search all temples, mosques etc. Right now i am using different search form for different one. How can i do this with only one search form???

One more thing I am using these modules for handling addresses and locations

```
Address Field - 7.x-1.0-beta3
Geofield - 7.x-1.1
GeoPHP - 7.x-1.6
Geocoder - 7.x-1.2
```

How can i search results based on city and locations?

Comment: Have you tried : http://drupal.org/project/finder ?

Comment: No, not yet i will check...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to make the searches by name, then you should use the same field for all the temples' names, regardless of their type. By doing that exposing that field will do what you want.

Comment: It depends on how you have your fields, could you provide more information? Otherwise we cannot help you.